# Redirect journald/systemd logs

Tags: postfix-mta, rsyslog, systemd-journald

I have been trying to get postgrey to log to rsyslog then to mail.log. I see the desired logs using the journald command. My question is is there a way to redirect those postgrey logs to rsyslog?

I've tried a lot of the suggestions in my other post that no one is answering now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.